# Volume of a $d$-dimensional Torus.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, reference-request, volume

Is there a known equation for the volume of a solid $d$-dimensional torus, that is $T = S^1_{r_1} \times B^{(d-1)}_{r_2}$, where $S^1_{r_1}$ is a circle of radius $r_1$ around which we revolve a $(d-1)$-dimensional ball $B^{(d-1)}_{r_2}$ of radius $r_{2}$? I can't seem to find a reference for this anywhere online.

Comment: I suppose it is $2 \pi r_1$ times the volume of the ball, which has a well known formula in terms of the gamma function.

Comment: This has very little to do with *general topology*. By Pappus's theorem the outcome is the expected one.

Comment: The theorem that Jack refers to is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem.